# POST method from Laravel controller called with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel, post

I wanted to update table automatically with button from main blade, with some entries.

Controller:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $x='47'; $y='16';

    $device_new = Device_new::where('deviceId', $id)->first();
    $device_new->x = $x;
    $device_new->y = $y;

    $device_new->save();

    return redirect('/welcome');
}
```

Button:

```
<div>
        <button type="submit" id="updatedevice">UPDATE MAP</button>
    </div>
```

Javascript (JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#updatedevice').click(function() {
    updatedev();
});

function updatedev() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/device_new',
        method: 'POST', 
    });
}
```

Now I gues, I should define something in 'updatedev' to execute this update. 
I made it with GET method, but this is bit confusing.

Any idea, could this work, or I should try it on some other way?

Comment: Did you get any errors after trying the current method?

Comment: Im getting error 405 in console

Comment: 405 stands for  "method not allowed"

Comment: if you are using resource route then you will have to make sure the route defined is post or put method.

Comment: Yes, I defined my method as POST in routes

Comment: Where does ``$id`` come from in you post method ?

Comment: Is that button in a form?

Comment: Nope. I made it just call function when it used.

Comment: you're updating. include `headers: {  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'  }` in you're ajax request. You `url` shouls also carry a param

Answer (score 0):

The post, put routes require a csrf token if enabled. To pass this use the `_method` for the method and  `_token` for the csrf token.

Change `method` to `_method` and add a crsf token.

```
function updatedev() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/device_new',
            _method: 'POST', 
            _token : "yourCsrfTokern!!"
        });
    }
```

also check your route and change `Route::get` to `Route::post`

Comment: Is this token required because I dont have update form here?

Comment: The token is required for every post route. So if you use the _methods post, put or delete. you have to add the crsf token. This isn't just for html forms. It is for every route that post,puts or deletes something. Check out why the crsf token is used here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AJAX and redirect to another page after the process is completed then `return redirect()` will not work for this.

In your case you should do something like:

In Controller:

```
return response()->json($data, $status); //string or array data and $status is https status
```

In JS:
You need to pass CSRF token from form too.

```
 $.ajax({
        url:'/device_new',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data //Your form data 
        success: function (response) {
          window.location.href = "/welcome";
    });
```